# looking for tips to automate some windows task

Tags: windows, automation

So here is the question I am facing currently:

on Windows PC.
I have a list of serial-numbers on Excel that I need to input to another proprietary application one at the time then I need to click couple buttons.

Finally, The proprietary application will run for a min or two after input.
Then I need to basically repeat the same task about 800 more times.

I think there must be a way/tools to automate this task?

I only need the tool/name or something to go off to do some of my research.

Any Tip will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: think AutoHotkey might be what I am looking for, but still open to suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Autoit (www.autoitscript.com) - Great helpfile and great community.